# Restrict client actions (server control)

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, node.js, timer

In a small project I am working the client is able to perform actions by *clicking in buttons* within a webpage. By clicking in those buttons he can trigger events that have an impact on the server. I wanted to forbide the client from triggering events too often (he can only trigger when 5 minutes have passed since the last trigger for example).

Only registered clients can trigger the events which means each client has a session id and an entry in a database. What I am doing to restrict the client actions is to update a database state when an event is triggered and check for that same state when the next call happens.

Flow example: Client clicks button --> Call is made to server --> Checks the state of the client in the database --> IF state is 0 triggers event,updates state to 1 and starts timer -- IF state is 1 does nothing.

I am currently facing **three** problems.

---

**Can't restrict the client actions fast enough**

If the client clicks too fast at the time the calls reach the server the database state is still 0. That allows for multiple calls to triger events before the database state is updated. In the worst case of hyper fast clicking about 6 events are triggered "at once".

I think I could restrict the client actions in the client-side at least to compensate for the secure server restriction delay. However I am not sure if that is 100% secure since I have heard that client is not to be trusted. Trusting him even by that small time lapse can be dangerous, no?

**Not sure of how I should keep track of multiple player trigger timers**

After some client triggers an event I start a server-side timer that when finished will update the clients trigger state back to 0 which will allow him to trigger an event once more. Code example follows:

```
function ControlEventTrigger (user_id,time) {

   var timer = setInterval(function() {  
     if(time == 0) {
        UpdateDatabaseState(user_id);  
        clearInterval(timer);
     } 
     time--;
   },1000);

}
```

Is this a good solution to handle multiple clients?

**Show the client the time until the next possible trigger even if the client reloads the page**

I am currently able to inform the client about the time left until he can trigger a new event by returning a variable *time* from the server side that is both used to keep track of the server side event timer and, in this case, to keep track of the client side timer. I return that value once when the event trigger happens. Both timers start almost at the same exact time and in the client side he can see the timer decreasing over time. (the delay between both timers is minimal).

What I also would like is to get the time until the next event trigger even when the user reloads the page. As it is now, when the user reloads the page I can't access the time left until the next event trigger. I think I would somehow need to access the server timer function and get the value of the user time at that specific moment and return it?

---

Communication client-server is ajax based. I can give more clarification if needed. Thank you.